# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '111' in ["dd","a","b","d","e","f","g"] , typeahead

Tags: typeahead

According to the [Typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/) and some [examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) found here. i keep geting error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '111' in ["dd","a","b","d","e","f","g"]

```
  <input id="searchDeveloper" class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="countries"/>

 $('#searchDeveloper').typeahead({                                
              name: 'countries',               
              prefetch: '/search',
              limit:10  
        });
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks :)

Comment: Please use more appropriate tags. That tag is for the generic concept of typing ahead, not the Javascript plugin.

Comment: Can you give the output of '/search' result set. It'll be helpful to know why it's failing.

Comment: "/search" result set is ["dd","a","b","d","e","f","g"]